# MySQL query IS NOT test against multiple values

Tags: mysql

Is there a better way to write the following 'where' portion of a mysql query:

```
WHERE t.status IS NOT 'resolved'
  AND t.status IS NOT 'closed'
  AND t.status IS NOT 'deleted'
```

can they be combined into a single where statement?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
WHERE t.status NOT IN ('resolved', 'closed', 'deleted')
```

Boolean algebra says these two expressions are equivalent:

```
NOT A AND NOT B AND NOT C

NOT (A OR B OR C)
```

This is [DeMorgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demorgan%27s_law).

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, it has been a while since I hand-coded my SQL statements myself.  I'm going to pin that name to my bulletin board here too! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, you need to consider cost issue before attempting to combine these into something more readable and smarter. Check your explain plan or equivalent for MySQL if this change results in an increased cost.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying, but I need to basically query all tickets for a tech, where the ticket is any status except 'resolved','closed', or 'deleted'.  In thinking about your statement though, if the database size becomes very large, it may be advantageous to either move those tickets to an archive table, or set the status column as an index.  At this point though, I just needed to simplify the query a bit.